# Node.js Retrieve URL Parameters from Server

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I need to pass a parameter (**qItems**) in **XMLHttpRequest.open**:

**index.html** (app.listen(8080);)

```
var qItems= 8;
var url= 'ItemsList';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var tag = document.getElementById("insertHere");
tag.innerHTML = "Loading...";
xhr.open("GET", url+"?qItems="+qItems, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
display(tag, xhr);
}
xhr.send(null);
```

But on Server side (**server.js**) use static URLs:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var directory = require('serve-index');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./data/DB.sqlite',function(err){
if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
    console.log('Connected to DB!');
});
app.get('/ItemsList', function(req, res) {
    db.all("SELECT rowid, iName, iDescrip FROM Items", function(err, row) {
    if (err !== null) {
      res.status(500).send("An error has occurred: " + err);
  } else {
    res.render('ItemsList.pug', {
   items: row
       }, function(err, html) {
            res.status(200).send(html)
     });
  }
});
});
```

I try (**server.js**):

```
app.get('/ItemsList?qItems='+qItems, function(req, res) {...}
```

But I get error: **qItems undefined** (from node.js)

Is there any way to get query parameters from Server side?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement a different handler for url with query params, `ItemsList/qItems=xxx`, query params are available to `/ItemsLists` GET handler in `req.query`.

```
app.get('/ItemsList', function(req, res) {
  // You can access qItems from query params
  var qItems = req.query.qItems
  ...
}
```